# Queue Implementation using Linked List: C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections, linked-list, queue

I am learning Data Structure. Today, I wanted to implement Queue using Linked List. As we have FRONT and REAR first index of the entry point of the Queue. If someone asks me to implement a Queue  with Linked List, please confirm my below implementation (I am able to achieve the Queue objective without the REAR object.)

Is this implementation valid?

```
class Queue
{
    Node head;
    class Node
    {
        public int Value;
        public Node next;

        public Node()
        {
            next = null;
        }
    }

    public void addElement(int val)
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            Node temp = new Node();
            temp.Value = val;
            head = temp;
            return;
        }

        Node tempNode = head;
        while (tempNode.next != null)
        {
            tempNode = tempNode.next;
        }

        Node newElement = new Node();
        newElement.Value = val;
        tempNode.next = newElement;
    }

    public void Dequeue()
    {
        if (head != null)
        {
            if (head.next != null)
            {
                head = head.next;
                return;
            }
            head = null;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Queue queue = new Queue();
        queue.addElement(10);
        queue.addElement(20);
        queue.addElement(30);
        queue.addElement(40);

        queue.Dequeue();
        queue.Dequeue();
        queue.Dequeue();
        queue.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post this instead to Code Review.

Comment: Reason for here: I would like to confirm that do we need to implement FRONT and REAR both the thing while implementing a Queue.

Comment: You don’t *need* to, just like you don’t *need* a linked list to create a queue. But having both changes things and one should know what happens with or without both. For example to performance/time complexity.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if we want to have *front* and *rear* ends, let's have them:

```
private Node m_Head;
private Node m_Tail;
```

You have just one `Node head;` field and that's why your implementation at least *inefficient*: you have `O(N)` time complexity to `addElement`:

```
...
while (tempNode.next != null)
{
    tempNode = tempNode.next;
}
...
```

When you can easily have `O(1)`

I suggest using *typical* names like `Enqueue` instead of `addElement` and have `Try` methods (often, we don't want exceptions if queue is empty). Finally, let's use generics: `MyQueue<T>` where `T` is item's type.

```
public class MyQueue<T> {
  private class Node {
    public Node(Node next, T value) {
      Next = next;
      Value = value;
    }

    public Node Next { get; internal set; }
    public T Value { get; }
  }

  private Node m_Head;
  private Node m_Tail;

  public void Enqueue(T item) {
    Node node = new Node(null, item);

    if (m_Tail == null) {
      m_Head = node;
      m_Tail = node;
    }
    else {
      m_Tail.Next = node;
      m_Tail = node;
    }
  }

  public bool TryPeek(out T item) {
    if (m_Head == null) {
      item = default(T);

      return false;
    }

    item = m_Head.Value;

    return true;
  }

  public T Peek() {
    if (m_Head == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty.");

    return m_Head.Value;
  }

  public bool TryDequeue(out T item) {
    if (m_Head == null) {
      item = default(T);

      return false;
    }

    item = m_Head.Value;
    m_Head = m_Head.Next;

    return true;
  }

  public T Dequeue() {
    if (m_Head == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue is empty.");

    T item = m_Head.Value;
    m_Head = m_Head.Next;

    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question: what is the use of TryDequeue and TryPeek.

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper: if we don't want have *exception* to be thrown on empty queue we can put, say, `TryDequeue` : `if (nyQueue.TryDequeue(out item)) {/* success*/} else {/*queue is empty*/}`